# Djano Queryset returned from Manager with Stored Procedure

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, rawsql

I have a `model.Manager` that runs a stored procedure and a `model.Model` to handle the returned data. However, when the data is returned, it's not returned as a `queryset` but instead a list of tuples, and I cannot reference them by field name.  I would like to have the results returned as a `queryset`.

models.py

```
class DashboardDetailManager(models.Manager):
    def dashboardDetail(self, from_date, to_date):
        from django.db import connections
        # AD 11/10/2020 updated sproc to return multiple sets for easier handling
        # was only returning the last set of expected results-->
        raw_sql = f"EXEC dbo.spGetDashDetailData @formFromDate = '{from_date}', @formToDate = '{to_date}'"
        with connections['ECS3'].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(raw_sql)
            detail_rows = []
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                detail_rows.append(row)
            while cursor.nextset():
                for row in cursor.fetchall():
                    detail_rows.append(row)

        return detail_rows



class DashDetailData(models.Model):
    occurred = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True);
    severity = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
    batchid = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True);
    hrefkey = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    id_cst = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    docType =  models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True);
    tpid =  models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True);
    name_cst =  models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True);
    message =  models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True);
    attachment =  models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True);
    bom_status =  models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True);
    ack =  models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True);
    bom_count = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = DashboardDetailManager()
```

views.py

`detail_rows = DashDetailData.objects.dashboardDetail('11-10-2020', '11-20-2020')`

Comment: I think you're looking for [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/).

Comment: Thanks!  I have read the documentation until my eyes are crossed, but I can't seem to sort through it in my head.  Was hoping for an example, or snippet so I can understand what I need.

Comment: I reread it this morning, and the way I understand it, I can't use it for sproc execution to use Manager.raw() you need to pass in an id to the select.

Comment: The thing is, you're going to have to engage in a process lovingly called "fiddling": trying something, seeing what the result is and tweak it or throw away the idea and start fresh. Stored procedures by nature are hard to abstract, because what they do is "up to the procedure". All Django has in terms of support is [this little bit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#calling-stored-procedures). So if you really want a queryset, you're going to have to dive into Django internals and see how Django builds one. This will be largely engine specific.

Comment: Oh, I love some good 'fiddling' :-)  But for this particular piece of my project, I'm just going to use row indexes and move on.  Thanks a bunch though, I appreciate your time!

Comment: Looking at the internals, django.db.models.query.ModelIterable is thing that does all the magic. It doesn't look too hard to strip it down to match your procedure ("famous last words").